# OpenID: Acceptance in non geek community for registration

Tags: openid

If we are going to develop a community website for non geeks, is it ok if we implement openid registration. How much openid is acceptable in non geek community. Anybody having any idea about this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do both - provide OpenID for those that want to use it and have a regular user account signup for those that don't. You could even go all the way and become an OpenID provider and allow users with regular accounts on your system to use them as OpenIDs on other systems.

In short, OpenID is OK as long as it's not the only option.

One small note: If you do decide to provide OpenID authentication, you need to be prepared for users [locking themselves out of their accounts](https://web.archive.org/web/20090407063154/http://stackoverflow.com:80/questions/347019/regaining-access-to-a-stackoverflow-profile). You should also provide a mechanism for [changing the associated OpenID](https://web.archive.org/web/20090424075552/http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com:80/pages/general/suggestions/16685).

Comment: And the same goes for 'geek' communities like this - not all of us like OpenID.

Comment: I thought OpenID was cool, but actually having to type in the URL by name because the system 'protects me from phishing' is too inconvenient. Luckily I only had to do this once.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should just stick with the standard email address and password, it's what everybody knows and gives you the benefit of having an automatic external point of contact with the users in case you need to notify them of something.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose both Open ID and Traditional login functionality. its becoming quite adaptable among non geeks also. You can even look for Google's [friend connect](http://www.google.com/friendconnect/) for further reference.

Answer (score 0):

We're just migrating an old site to a new (WordPress-based) platform. We're confronting this issue, we know we want to outsource the credential-management to something like OpenID, although currently FaceBook Connect is the leader in our planning. Mainly because a significant proportion of our users are already there.

We could look to do both, but if a decent proportion of your base is not already OpenIDed-up then to non-Geeks it's not compelling. Equally I do believe that the OpenID model is fundamentally A Good Thing so you could argue that teaching a little more of the world about it has some moral good associated with it.

Answer (score 0):

I think non-geeks don't see the benefits of using OpenId and most OpenID logons do a poor job of stating what they do.

To address your concerns, if you're going to implement OID, then do a good job of explaining what it does and what benefits it has.